# How many ways n cars can park in n spaces if each car can only park side to side to another one, except the first?

Tags: combinatorics

Couldn't find a better answer for this problem. May someone help me, please?

A row of $n$ cars is ready to enter a parking lot with only one row with $n$ spaces side by side. The first car can choose any of the $n$ spaces, but the following vehicles can only park side to another car that is already parked. How many ways all the cars can occupy the empty spaces?

I solved choosing arbitrary values for n and calculating the possible combinations.

Supose $n=3$ and A,B,C are ours cars, being A the first to parking, B the second and C the third. Then the combinations are:

Notation: (I use "/" to separate combinations where A chooses different spaces)

ABC / BAC, CAB/ CBA

Supose $n=4$ and A,B,C,D are ours cars:

ABCD/BACD, CABD, DABC/ DBAC, DCAB, CBAD/ DCBA

Lastly, $n=5$ and A,B,C,D,E are ours cars:

ABCDE /BACDE, CABDE, DABCE, EABCD/ DCABE, DBACE, CBADE, EDABC, ECABD, EBACD/ EDCAB,ECBAD,DCBAE,EDBAC/ EDCAB, ECBAD, DCBAE, EDBAC/ EDCBA

Let $C$ be the number of possible combinations counted above for each n, we have these pairs:

When $n=3$, $C=4$

$n=4$, $C=8$

$n=5$, $C=16$

So then I come up by these results that $C = {2}^{(n-1)}$. These formula works when n=2 and n=1 too, but I'm not sure if it's correct and I know there must be a better way than that.

PS: English is not my first language and I'm new to this forum (2nd post), so please let me know if I did something wrong or if the explanation is too confusing so I can edit it.

Comment: Hint: Ignore the first car. Every car after that can be parked either L or R of the existing cars. Show that this leads to a unique placement of the first car. Thus, create a bijection.

Comment: Alternative analysis to that of @CalvinLin.  Let $~f(n)~$ denote the number of satisfying ways that $~n~$ cars can be parked.  Consider the parking of the cars in reverse order.  It is impossible for there to be a gap for the last car to fill.  Therefore, the last car must be parked at one of the ends.  This implies that $~f(n) = 2f(n-1),~$ since (for example) placing the last car at the first position permits the other $~(n-1)~$ cars to be parked in $~f(n-1)~$ different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Place the first car somewhere in an **open row**
- Now each remaining car can go either just to the left or just to the right of those already parked, yielding  # of ways $ =\boxed{2^{n-1}}$
- We have now obtained the  **patterns** of a successful parking which has an exact correspondence (bijection) with our $n$ parking slots

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand how you got to $2^{n-1}$. Could you explain your reasoning for $n=3$ and $n=4$ if it's not too much trouble, please?

Comment: I have simplified the wording, still to illustrate,  $n=4, A \mid AB, BA \mid ABC, CAB, BAC,CBA \mid ABCD, DABC, CABD, DCAB, BACD, DBAC, CBAD, DCBA$